# Using generics with reduce

Tags: typescript

I have a `counts` function that takes an array of elements and returns counts of each unique item, like `uniq -c`:

```
counts(['a', 'b', 'a']) // => {a: 2, b: 1}
```

The following implementation works but violates the [prefer-reduce-type-parameter rule](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/blob/master/packages/eslint-plugin/docs/rules/prefer-reduce-type-parameter.md):

```
// Works with eslint warning
function counts<K extends number | string | symbol>(els: K[]): Record<K, number> {
  return els.reduce((acc, cur) => {
    acc[cur] = acc[cur] ? acc[cur] + 1 : 1

    return acc
  }, {} as Record<K, number>)
}
```

However, when I remove the cast and add a type parameter to `reduce` I get an error:

```
// Fails with
// error TS2322: Type 'K' is not assignable to type 'Record<K, number>'.
//   Type 'string | number | symbol' is not assignable to type 'Record<K, number>'.
//     Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'Record<K, number>'.
// error TS2345: Argument of type '{}' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Record<K, number>'.
function counts<K extends number | string | symbol>(els: K[]): Record<K, number> {
  return els.reduce<Record<K, number>>((acc, cur) => {
    acc[cur] = acc[cur] ? acc[cur] + 1 : 1

    return acc
  }, {})
}
```

Comment: I'd prefer to [avoid `.reduce` entirely](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qaGjS7-qWzg) in these sorts of situations, it can be hard to work with in TS. A `for` loop is often nicer

Comment: The value `{}` is not known to be assignable to `Record<K, number>`, right?  If `K` is `"a"`, then `{}` would have to be of type `{a: string}` which it's not.  Hence you need a type assertion if you want the compiler to ignore that while you get your accumulator ready.  Why do you care about the "prefer-reduce-type-parameter rule" anyway?

Comment: I may not be understanding correctly, but what's problem with this: https://tsplay.dev/4Wy8bm

Comment: @jcalz I don't especially care about that rule but was trying to glean the supposed benefits that came with it. I'm not sure why casting works with "a" but this approach doesn't.

Comment: @Nishant interesting, thanks for that

Comment: Type assertions (what you are calling "casting") work because they intentionally let you do unsafe things.  You can say `const x = {} as {a: string}` but not `const y: {a: string} = {}`.

Comment: What an awkward rule